# Fetching JSON from form data

Tags: php, html, json

I am writing a code to fetch JSON parameter sent using form.

I have this html

```
<form action="jsonfile.php" method="POST" name="myForm" enctype="application/json">
    <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname"></p>

    <p><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname"></p>

    <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="submitform()">
</form>
```

And json here

```
<script>
    var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jsonfile.php",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : "application/json",
    success: function(result){

    }
  });
</script>
```

**NOW**, i want get the values of the above form sent as json in the other file called **JSONFILE.PHP**. I don't really know what should i use to decord the data into JSON DATA.

Thank you.

Comment: The form is submitted by the submit button, not by the ajax call. So, submitfirm() maybe has a e.preventDefault for not submitting the form and calling the ajax? or what submitform() do? post that function and we help you.

Comment: just `$_POST` ? share your php file

Comment: show your php code, what you have done for this.

Comment: @Roy the it doesn't matter where jquery submit OR the "submit" button. What i need is just how to fetch the passed JSON to next file and access it

Answer (score 0):

```
    // HTML Code
<form method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm" enctype="application/json" onsubmit="return false">
    <p><label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="fname"></p>
    <p><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lname"></p>

    <input value="Submit" type="submit" >
</form>

   // JavaScript Code
<script>
    $("#myForm").submit(function () {
        var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jsonfile.php",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });
    });
</script>

// PHP Code jsonfile.php
    <?php
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    if ($data) {
        print_r($data);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: seems the PHP Code jsonfile.php you suggested hasn't been working correctly. I apparently showing blank instead of showing the JSON parameters of the values.

Though, Thanks

Comment: `https://tariqrasheed.com/projects/code/50450620/` Please check the network call.